# Why does fgets on OS X output a BELL (^G, ascii: 07) character when input exceeds expected length?

Tags: c, xcode, macos

Test-case program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 1024
int main(int args,char *argv[]){
  char buf[SIZE];
  fgets(buf, SIZE, stdin);
  return 0;
}
```

Example usage (i.e. entering 1024 `x` characters):

```
bash-3.2$ gcc read.c -o read
bash-3.2$ ./read
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
^G
```

On OS X, this beeps the terminal and waits. I can hit RET again and it beeps again. If I run it in a pipe or from Emacs's shell, I see the `^G` character being outputted.

With the same exact invocation on my Ubuntu VM, the program completes as expected (i.e. read 1023 bytes into `buf` and null-terminate it).

This is interrupting a program I'm trying to write (in another language, but uses the C library underneath) that takes in lines of JSON as part of a command interface. So the question is: how do I disable this behaviour in OS X? Is there an API call to turn it off? Perhaps an environment variable? It's so bizzare.

Comment: Because Apple has always been annoying ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent this behavior by adding this to your `~/.bash_profile` file:

```
stty -imaxbel
```

This command is documented in this Apple [manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stty.1.html) for the `stty` program.

> imaxbel (-imaxbel)
>                    The system imposes a limit of MAX_INPUT (currently 255) characters in the input queue.  If
>                    imaxbel is set and the input queue limit has been reached, subsequent input causes the system
>                    to send an ASCII BEL character to the output queue (the terminal beeps at you). Otherwise,
>                    if imaxbel is unset and the input queue is full, the next input character causes the
>                    entire input and output queues to be discarded.

You also have the choice of manually issuing `stty -imaxbel` in your current shell. Without adding it to a startup file (like `~/.bash_profile`) the setting will revert to its default the next time you log in.

If you require line buffering to be disabled and every character passed to the program as it is typed then one way is to use `stty cbreak` . One of the primary things it changes is to disable `icanon` mode which controls whether you are in buffered line mode or not. This [article](https://blog.nelhage.com/2009/12/a-brief-introduction-to-termios-termios3-and-stty/) has a reasonable discussion in layman terms of `cbreak` and `icanon`:

> ICANON - Perhaps the most important bit in c_lflag is the ICANON bit. Enabling it enables "canonical" mode – also known as "line editing" mode. When ICANON is set, the terminal buffers a line at a time, and enables line editing. Without ICANON, input is made available to programs immediately (this is also known as "cbreak" mode).

You may be able to get the results you are looking for by a command like:

```
stty cbreak -imaxbel
```

This goes into character by character mode and ensures the *BEL* is disabled.

Comment: This solves the problem of the BEL character, but as in the docs you included, the input is discarded when it exceeds MAX_INPUT, unlike on Linux which has the (more useful) behaviour of consuming what was provided and leaving the rest on the buffer. Currently I'm unable to consume a line >=1024 characters in length on OS X. To solve this either the discarding behaviour needs to be disabled or the MAX_INPUT needs to be extended to something much higher, otherwise I'll have to chunk all my client's inputs into MAX_INPUT-size chunks.

Comment: @ChristopherDone You may have to consider the `cbreak` option (partially cooked mode). You can try turning it on via `stty cbreak -imaxbel` . It may work

Comment: Can you update the answer? I don't know how you came to find this syntax. The man page wasn't enough for me to come to the same conclusion as you. I'll mark yours as correct once updated.

Comment: @ChristopherDone : I have made an addition to my answer.